# customizing google maps V.3 streetview controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I've got one instance of google maps with fully customized options in my app.The users are able to switch to street view if they want to and come back all with the same instance of the map.

Is there a way to customize streetview controls when creating the map instance, along with the other map options?

I can not see any documentation on how to do that on the main map, while if you directly instantiate a the street view on a separate dom element you can do that like this:

```
var panoramaOptions = {
    zoomControl: false,
    linksControl: false,
    panControl: false
}
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_streetview"), panoramaOptions)
mymap.setStreetView(panorama)
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

You may access the streetView-property of a map(no matter if custom or default) by using the `getStreetView()`-method of the map.

Use the `setOptions()`-method of the streetView to set the options:

```
mymap.getStreetView().setOptions(panoramaOptions);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like setOptions exists anymore on v3 - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama